# Clustering extremely high-dimensional time series data

Tags: clustering, references, high-dimensional

I am a student researcher with a very large array of time series data of about 100,000 variables over 7,000 time steps. I suspect that many of these variables naturally derive from functional clusters and would like to compute these clusters. Unfortunately, I'm at a loss for how to cluster this amount of data reasonably and efficiently. Many of the solutions I have attempted are either vastly too slow, require too much memory, or are just general "dimensionality reduction" approaches which convolute variables instead of simply clustering - not really what I want.

For example, my first approach was to try to compute the correlation matrix and then apply a biclustering algorithm to "block" variables into clusters, however, since the correlation matrix is absolutely gigantic, I don't know if that is feasible at all.

What kind of clustering approaches exist to handle high-dimensional time series data?